# Sort alphabet letters using a Binary tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree

I came across an interview question which states: How would you represent the letters `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `E`, `F` and `G` in a sorted order using a binary tree representation?

It's really stumped me. If we take `G` to be the root of the tree then the left child would `E` and the right child would be `F` so that the right subtree is "greater than" the left subtree. Then for the node E, its left child would be A and the right child `B` and `F`'s left child would be `C` and its right child would be `D`.

Is that correct or does anyone else have a different answer?

Comment: You should probably look up what "sorted order" means. Hint: If G is the root, it won't have a right child.

Answer (score 6):

The binary tree that you described is a [Binary heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap), which is usually used to implement priority queue.

Instead, use [Binary search tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree), which keeps their keys in sorted order.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using the letters from A to G as your complete set, the sorted binary tree would look like:

```
      D
  B       F  
A   C   E   G
```

Comment: If you research building a complete binary tree (or binary heap) as @Yu stated, all sub-trees are full. This means that it will take log(n) time to search for what you're looking for (where n = number of nodes). As you build the tree, taking nodes from A to G as they come, D will emerge the root of the tree as this allows for all other nodes to form complete binary sub-trees.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer to the question is incorrect. Why?
When you take G as the root then all the other alphabets or keys must be on the left side of G. Meaning G will not have a right child since all nodes that form a right subtree must have greater keys than the reference key value, in this case, G.